# Where can I buy a "roaming" or "international" SIM card — one with attached phone numbers in multiple countries?

Tags: cellphones, international-travel, roaming

In the past I have found two companies that offered one sim card with multiple (international) numbers attached to it. The first one, of which I forgot the name, offered one sim card with the possibility to add different european numbers to it. They don't longer exist, hopefully because they were ahead of their time.

I recently learned of the existence of a [Surinamese company](http://www.telesur.nl/telesurnederland/website/home.asp?menuid=2) that offers a so called "two country sim". It gives both a Surinamese and a Dutch mobile telephone number. You are always available through both numbers. Both in the Netherlands and in Suriname you won't have roaming costs. The company aims at the large Surinamese community in the Netherlands.

I do like this concept. Since I travel frequently I would really like to have such a sim card. Since telesur proves that the technology works, there should be others. Does anyone know of similar companies, preferably combining Belgian, Dutch, German, French and UK numbers?

Comment: I'm looking at the Telesur website, but I don't see any info on them actually selling one sim card serving two countries (I speak Dutch). I suspect they keep tariffs low in Holland and Suriname by routing calls through their partners in these two countries. This is similar to how Airtel does it in a dozen African countries: A sim card from Kenya (on Airtel) works in Uganda (on Airtel) because Airtel recognizes the foreign sim card as its own and then charges local rates.

Comment: You are right they don't mention that they are serving two countries, but I know they do since relatives of mine living in Suriname have this card. I call them on their Dutch number and their Surinamese number rings if they are in Suriname. I don't pay international fee's, they don't pay the roaming. When in the Netherlands they Dutch number is active

Comment: @MastaBaba The details on the two country sim (in Dutch) are here: http://www.telesur.nl/telesurnederland/website/page.asp?sessionid=5BBE46F483FD40D2B85C9CC8E110D74E&menuid=6

Comment: I really hate telecommunication companies for their greed. I believe they can make this happen but greed stops them. You know, sometimes I feel this kind of sim cards will never be available till end of time.

Comment: Sounds like something of limited benefit. Having roaming and/or 2 different sim cards would solve just about all your travel needs?

Comment: @Rory Except being easily reachable from several countries. Even if you are willing to pay extortion rates for roaming or play with multiple SIM cards you still need to let people know where you are/which SIM you are using or get them to call a foreign number. The only solution is carrying several mobile phones but that's just annoying.

Answer (score 10):

What you're probably looking for is often called a "Roaming SIM" or "International SIM". These have numbers for multiple countries attached to them, and generally lower costs to make/receive calls (and sometimes also texts and data) in those countries.

Depending on the one you go for, they may have varying numbers of countries covered from the start, and you may or may not be able to add new countries as needed.

Personally, I have one from [TruPhone](http://www.truphone.com/en-GB/Products/Tru-for-you/), but there are a number of other companies out there. With TruPhone, you get one number as standard which is in your home country. As you need them, you add numbers from other countries (from a small-ish list) on a month-by-month basis. Their costs work well for the kind of travelling I do, but it's worth checking out others as the overall cost varies between provides based on the number of countries you need numbers for, the length of time you want numbers, how many calls you do in+out of country etc.

(Handy TruPhone hint - their customer service team on email and phone have always proved utterly useless whenever I've had problems. Instead, describe your issue in 140 characters and post it on twitter, then someone clueful from TruPhone very quickly pops up and helpfully solves your problem!)

I'd say as a general rule, if you go to just one or two countries very often, it'll be cheaper to get a pay-as-you-go SIM card from that country. However, that sim probably won't work when you're home though, sometimes unless you pay extra, sometimes never, so it depends if you need the number to always work or not. If you visit lots of different countries, and/or need to give out various stable and always working country numbers (and you don't want to do call forwarding), then an international sim may be best. Do the maths yourself and decide!